# Prevent contenteditable adding same classes on enter

Tags: jquery, html

I have set `contenteditable="true"` to `ul`, and I have a list inside this. 
 As you can see before each list I've set `checkboxes`. If I click on checkbox, it toggles class `checked`. The problem is, when I click checkbox, and press enter, it adds same class `checked` to this added list. 
I don't want added list to be checked. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'ul li',  function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
   })
    $(document).on('click', 'ul li span',  function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
   })
});
```

```css
li:before {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  display: block;
  float: left;
  content: "";
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   background-size: 100%;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
    height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    width: 99%;
}
li.checked:before {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width:90%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul contenteditable="true" id="editor">
   <li>
     <span>
       Click on checbox and press enter
     </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your requirements you can add an event listener to detect any change in the `ul` section and remove the class from the last `li` tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'ul li',  function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
   });
    $(document).on('click', 'ul li span',  function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
  $('#editor').on('input', function(){
    $(this).children('li').last().removeClass('checked');
  });
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/VeeK727/pen/BzdkJK)

You don't have to even check the checkbox, you can edit the contents anyway. That's because you've set the property of the ul in such a way `contenteditable="true"`. I'm not sure why you'd want that but if you must, then you can disable this property after the checkbox has been checked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'ul li',  function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.toggleClass('checked');
     if($this.hasClass('checked')){
       $this.parent().attr('contenteditable', false);
     }
     else {
       $this.parent().attr('contenteditable', true);
     }
   })
    $(document).on('click', 'ul li span',  function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this disable enter keypress. I need to add lists with enter.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm creating a ToDo List. So, for exmp, you create a task in first list, if you do that task, you click checkbox and mark as done. If you want to add another task, just click enter and you can add another task. And this new task should be unchecked! Am I clear?

Comment: Thank you, @VeeK! This works just in one case. Just if you add list one after the other, without turning back. If you add many li-s, and turn back and mark check one checkbox, press enter, you can see that is the same issue! :(

Comment: Might I suggest using a pre made plugin instead of inventing it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean! What kind of plugin?

Comment: Thank you very much, @VeeK! I already looked almost every plugin, but no one of them is what I'm looking for. Almost on each plugin, there is a list of contenteditables inside each list. What I'm trying to do, is that all the content should be contenteditable(Just one contenteditable). With this you can manipulate many things: navigation through list with arrow keys, select all content and delete all at one etc...

Comment: Check out this one: http://stephentvedt.com/examples/editable-storage/, this is what I want. Everything worked fine, but when I added checkboxes before each li, I faced many issues. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116813/discussion-between-veek-and-teuta-koraqi).

Answer (score 0):

I found the right solution of my answer: The solution was listening `DOMNodeInserted` event:

```
  $('#editor').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
     $(e.target).removeClass('checked');
   });
```